# Consider the equation $y''+\omega ^2y=A\cos (\omega x)$ where $A, \omega$ are positive constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation
\begin{equation*}
y''+\omega ^2y=A\cos (\omega x)
\end{equation*}
where $A, \omega$ are positive constants.

(a) Find all solutions on $0\leq x < \infty$.

(b) Show that every solution $\phi$ is such that $|\phi (x)|$ assumes arbitrarily large values as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

(c) Sketch the graph of that solution $\phi$ satisfying $\phi (0)=0$, $\phi '(0)=1$.

**Attempt:**

For $a)$, note that it is a linear equation with constant coefficients. The characteristic polynomial is
\begin{equation*}
p(r)=r^2+\omega^2
\end{equation*}
whose roots are $i\omega$ and $-i\omega$. Consequently, the general solution for $y''+\omega ^2y=0$ is
\begin{equation*}
\phi_h=c_1\cos \omega x + c_2\sin \omega x
\end{equation*}
The process is a bit long... The solution is
\begin{equation*}
\phi=\frac{Ax\sin \omega x}{2\omega}+ c_1\cos \omega x + c_2\sin \omega x
\end{equation*}
For $b)$, it can be seen to be true; but how do I prove it? what argument is suficeintes?
For $c)$, we obtain $c_1=0$ y $c_2=\frac{1}{\omega}$. But I don't have the graph.

Comment: Part b doesn't make sense. Have you left anything out from it?

Comment: There should be a relation between the $c_i$ values which you get by plugging into the equation.

Comment: BTW, what is $\phi$?

Comment: @mattos The exercise is number 4, page 70. Coddington-An introduction Ordinary Differential Equations. According to me I copied it as it is.

Comment: @Moti The general solution of the differential equation.

Comment: I would expect to see y in the final solution. Do you mean that $\phi = y$?

Comment: Yes, it is the Coddington notation.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{Ax\sin \omega x}{2\omega}$ can be arbitrarily large by choosing large value of $x$.

That’s enough for part b.

Try plotting graph on geogebra or other graphing tool.

Comment: So, the values you calculate for $c_1$ and $c_2$ are correct?